# After changing from 4.3.2 to 4.4 I get often status UNKNOWN where I got SATISFIABLE or UNSATISFIABLE first

Tags: z3

My scenario is as follows:

- First I follow the optimistic assumptions that all is well; so I check the assertions without asking for an unsat core (just using Assert).
- When I however get status UNSATISFIABLE during one of the tests I change the strategy and use AssertAndTrack from the very beginning to get the full unsat core.

With version 4.3.2 this works perfectly, but after switching to 4.4 (stable and latest) Z3 often returns status UNKNOWN (even for checks which delivered SATISFIABLE in 4.4 without AssertAndTrack).

Does anybody can give me a hint how to solve the problem or what to do to further analyze the problem?

Thanks

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second argument for assert-and-track you will need to pass a propositional atom or a negation of one. It was not fully checked in previous versions. This may be an explanation of why you are seeing different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I used the syntax of

```
AssertAndTrack(BoolExpr constraint, BoolExpr p)
```

the lazy way:

```
 AssertAndTrack(constraint, constraint)
```

and always got the conflicting constraints directly as feedback!

From version 4.4 on this is obviously no longer possible: the second parameter has to be another BoolExpr!  I cannot tell what the rules are here, but now I use labels and a dictionary to get the feedback and everything works fine again.